# Unique Count based on the two columns with DAX in Power BI

Tags: count, powerbi, match, row, daxstudio

I would like to get the unique count based on the two columns.

In Excel I am applying the following formula =IF(A3="Not Paid",1,IF(MATCH(B3,B:B,0)=ROW(),1,0)) but I don't know how can I apply the same logic in Power BI.

I am looking for DAX solutions to achieve my final result.

Data

```html
Colour  Combine Unique Count
A1  123 3000 A1 1
A1  124 4000 A1 1
A2  125 5000 A2 1
A2  126 6000 A2 1
Not Pair    127 7000 Not Pair   1
Not Pair    128 8000 Not Pair   1
A1  135 3000 A1 1
A2  135 6000 A2 1
A2  136 5000 A2 1
A2  136 6000 A2 1
A1  137 3000 A1 1
Not Pair    137 7000 Not Pair   1
Not Pair    137 8000 Not Pair   1
A1  138 4000 A1 1
Not Pair    138 7000 Not Pair   1
Not Pair    138 8000 Not Pair   1
A1  139 3000 A1 1
Not Pair    139 7000 Not Pair   1
A1  140 4000 A1 1
Not Pair    140 7000 Not Pair   1
A2  141 5000 A2 1
Not Pair    141 7000 Not Pair   1
Not Pair    141 8000 Not Pair   1
```

[image]

Comment: can you post sample output result table?

Comment: Unique count is my desired result based on the colour and combine column.

Comment: Herewith attached the PBI link for your reference. I am looking for DAX (New calculated column). In Excel I am applying the following =IF(A3="Not Paid",1,IF(MATCH(B3,B:B,0)=ROW(),1,0))

formula.https://www.dropbox.com/s/pe2cg3q7iwaw9ho/Match%20and%20Rows-SOF-25-09-2021.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a calculated column
[image]

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Can you please advise it's measure or new calculated column. Sorry I new to Power Bi. Please advise.

Comment: Its new calculated column. If you like the answer accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The result not matched according to final result. Could you please advise and help me. Combine
198 4000 A1
200 4000 A1
198 3000 A1
156 4000 A1
156 5000 A2
155 4000 A1
149 4000 A1
148 3000 A1
147 6000 A2

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jherglz8y3zzfvz/Match%20and%20Rows-SOF-25-09-2021.pbix?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfvhmesmp7f5esj/DAX%20ERROR-SS.PNG?dl=0

Comment: I added the file reference for your information. could you please have a look and advise.

Comment: create a new calculated column and paste the code I gave

Comment: Exactly I did the same thing but I got different result. If it possible could you please share the file please. DAX = IF (Data[Colour]="NOT PAIR" || CALCULATE(COUNT(Data[Combine]),ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Combine]))=1,1,0)

Comment: I can't copy your code because it's snapshot so I have to type it.

Comment: Not Pair is right one.

Comment: @johon can you please explain little bit, what this excel formula is doing, specially the 2nd if. I am not an excel user. I can give you a measure and in DAX if you can use a measure, don't use calculated column as it has performance implication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. I looking for New calculated option instead of measure. The 2nd if trying to give a count based on the two columns. Please look at the combine and colour column 147 6000 A2 and A2 has repeated twice therefore the formula giving count first instance and second one is 0.

Comment: any help please